# Can I say sheer sky?

Tags: adjectives

Can I say "sheer sky" to describe absolute sky? Does this sound right? Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: What does absolute sky mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sheer%20sky%2C%20sheer%20blue&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csheer%20sky%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csheer%20blue%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csheer%20sky%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csheer%20blue%3B%2Cc0) says it exists,

[image]

but in comparison with ***sheer blue***, it is rarely used. ***sky*** is not very compatible with degrees of intensity, so the phrase is uncommon. However, it really depends on your context. I am sure there can be circumstances when you can use it, for poetic purposes, or even in colloquial language.

Comment: 0.000000050 per cent is very rare.